# Spring framework json character error

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc, character-encoding

I am using spring framework for SOA rest services. My service is working good by i have a problem with characters. My service not accept non-english characters.For example; IıĞğÜüŞşİiÖöÇç => I???Üü???iÖöÇç. I googled this but i cant find a solution. Thanks for advices :)

My web.xml

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath*:com/yildizapp/resources/spring/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>yappServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath*:com.yildizapp.resources.web/applicationContext-web.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>yappServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<filter>
    <filter-name>characterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>characterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern> /* </url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

my applicationContext-web.xml

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="messageConverters">
        <list>
            <ref bean="jsonMessageConverter"/>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="jsonMessageConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
</bean>
```

my controller

```
@Autowired
private UserServiceDao userServiceDao;

@RequestMapping(value = "/register",method = RequestMethod.POST,produces = "application/json; charset=UTF-8 ")
@ResponseBody
public void saveUser(@RequestBody UserServiceRequest userServiceRequest){
    UserService userService=new UserService();
    userService.setName(userServiceRequest.getName());
    userService.setSurname(userServiceRequest.getSurname());
    userService.setPhoneNumber(userServiceRequest.getPhoneNumber());
    userService.setUsername(userServiceRequest.getUsername());
    userService.setPassword(userServiceRequest.getPassword());
    userService.setEmail(userServiceRequest.getEmail());
    userService.setDepartment(userServiceRequest.getDepartment());
    userServiceDao.save(userService);
}
```

Comment: Sounds like a character encoding problem. What character encoding does your application expect? Is the input in a different encoding than what the application expects?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe some configuration is misleading Jackson. You could try adding

```
consumes = "application/json; charset=UTF-8 "
```

to your Request Mapping